# Slow VBA Code optimisation

Tags: vba, excel

I´m pretty new to VBA and since it´s making my job so much easier I try to write some codes from time to time and everything works fine except for this one, I already tried with the Screen Updating and the Status Bar method but it´s still very slow. Any ideas on how it coul be improved? Thnak you

```
    Sub DW()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Dim i As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, &quot;A&quot;).End(xlUp).Row

    i = 1
    Do Until i > LastRow
    If Range("B" & i) = Range(B & i + 1) Then
    Range("L" & i) = Range("L" & i) + Range("L" & i + 1)
    Range("M" & i) = Range("M" & i) + Range("M" & i + 1)
    Range("N" & i) = Range("N" & i) + Range("N" & i + 1)
    Range("O" & i) = Range("O" & i) + Range("O" & i + 1)
    Range("P" & i) = Range("P" & i) + Range("P" & i + 1)
    Range("Q" & i) = Range("Q" & i) + Range("Q" & i + 1)
    Range("A" & i + 1).EntireRow.Delete
    LastRow = LastRow - 1

    Else
    i = i + 1
    End If
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: I'm  not near a computer just now but would recommend you consider ado recordsets. Search populating same from excel and the copyfromrecordset method to write the results back into excel. Just hints, sorry I can't offer more just now.

Comment: Turn off Automatic Calculations, store the range values in variables, put the variable into the ranges, and turn automatic calculations back on when your loop is done.

Comment: What is this "&quot;A&quot;"?

Comment: Consider change the FormulaR1C1 instead. `Range("L" & i).Resize(,6).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC+R[1]C"`, and do pause the auto calculation.

Comment: Turn off Calculations (like nemmy).  Are the contents of the cells text?   Are you adding values (Sum?) to an existing number?  You'd be better off using Cell.Offset or ActiveCell.Offset(i+1,11)  instead of Range("L" & i + 1) assuming A1 is starting point.  I would store the number in the row above into a variable add the row below then assign the value into the destination.  Your logic only accounts for 1 and only 1 duplicate key in Column B (sorted).  If B2, B3, B4 all had a value of 2 then in your loop B3 would be deleted, but B4 and B2 would remain because it would go down 1 after delete.

Answer (score 0):

This does what your code does; i tested with 1k rows of data and it was faster then your code.  (Updated with ja72's input)

```
Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

    If Range("B1") = Range("B2") Then
        Rows(1).Copy
        Rows(1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Cells(1, 12).Formula = "=SUM(L2:L" & LastRow & ")"
        Cells(1, 12).Resize(, 5).FillRight
    End If

    Range("L1").Resize(1,10).Value = Range("L1").Resize(1,10).Value

    Rows(2 & ":" & Rows.Count).Delete
```

Comment: This feels like a kludge, and the `.Value = .Value` statements seem odd, although I understand they are used to convert formulas into values. A better way would be with one statement like  `Range("L1").Resize(1,10).Value = Range("L1").Resize(1,10).Value`. Also I find the use of string math of addressing very error prone and difficult to maintain. The VBA gods gave us `.Offset()` and `.Resize()` for a reason.

Comment: @ja72 good input, resize makes a lot of sense. I will start using it,

Comment: @Gmalc thank you, I tried the code but it just deletes everything except for the first row

Comment: @MarcoC, I tested the code you provided and your code added each row to the row above it and then deletes the row you just added `r.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete`, keeping the total in the first row. My code sums each column in the first row and then deletes all the rows below.

Answer (score 0):

The code below first addresses the issue of string math for the range picking. Instead of `.Range("A" & i)` it best to use `.Offset()` or `.Cells()` instead. Additionally it makes it explicit that we are dealing with values and not ranges when the math takes place. It is recommended to always type `.Value` where it is implied.

```
Sub DW()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Dim i As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim r As Range, g As Range
    ' Set the start of the optimization loop
    Set r = Range("B1")
    ' While still inside the data
    Do While r.Row <= LastRow
        ' Check this value with value of next row
        If r.Value = r.Offset(1, 0).Value Then
            Set g = r.Offset(0, 10) ' Pick column "L" of same row as r
            Go from "L" to "Q"
            For i = 1 To 6
                'Add values one by one with row below
                g.Offset(0, i - 1).Value = _
                    g.Offset(0, i - 1).Value + g.Offset(1, i - 1).Value
            Next i
            r.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
            LastRow = LastRow - 1
        End If
        ' Move to next row
        Set r = r.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
End Sub
```

Depending on the total amount of data, it will be way faster to load all the data into memory and process it with VBA arrays only to be returned back in the end to the worksheet.

**The following code should be orders of magnitude faster.**

```
Sub DW2()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, i_out As Long, i_next As Long

    Dim LastRow As Long, ValCol As Long, LastCol As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    ValCol = Cells(, "L").Column
    LastCol = Cells(, "Q").Column

    Dim r_data As Range
    ' Reference all the data (filled rows, and 17 columns "A:Q")
    Set r_data = Range("A1").Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

    ' x is input data, y as output data
    Dim x() As Variant, y() As Variant

    ' Copy all the table cells into memory
    x = r_data.Value

    ' Create an empty array at least the same size
    ReDim y(1 To LastRow, 1 To LastCol)
    ' i_out is index for output
    i_out = 1
    ' i is index for input
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        ' Debug.Print "Row"; i, "into Row:"; i_out
        'Copy all values first from current row
        For j = 1 To LastCol
            y(i_out, j) = x(i, j)
        Next j
        ' Index i_next peeks at the next row
        i_next = i + 1
        If i_next >= LastRow Then
            ' Advance i_out
            i_out = i_out + 1
            Exit For
        End If
        ' Check with value match on 2nd column "B"
        Do While x(i, 2) = x(i_next, 2)
            'Add up values in columns 11 through 17
            For j = ValCol To LastCol
                y(i_out, j) = y(i_out, j) + x(i_next, j)
            Next j
            ' Peek at subsequent rows also
            i_next = i_next + 1
            If i_next >= LastRow Then
            ' Advance i_out
                i_out = i_out + 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Loop
        ' Advance i if rows were skipped
        i = i_next - 1
        ' Advance i_out
        i_out = i_out + 1
    Next i

    ' Clear all table cells
    r_data.ClearContents
    ' Overwrite with the optimized values
    r_data.Resize(i_out - 1, LastCol).Value = y
End Sub
```

<sub>Edit: Now tested for robustness when matching rows exist in the end of the data</sub>

Comment: both your codes have flaws: the first misses rows when deleting them. the second lets `l` variable exceed `LastRow ` in the `While  Wend` loop. I'm down voting it andI'll up vote it should you edit and amend your codes. (BTW this latter is quite an obsolete way of iterating and people prefer `Do While ...Loop` or `Do... Loop While` constructs.)

Comment: @DisplayName - It is not going past the last row because ` x(i, 2) = x(l, 2)` would return false. Unless the last cell in the "B" column is empty. For the first answer, I did testing and didn't see the flaw. Can you explain please? I have made edits to the code.

Comment: @DisplayName - Yes, but I made up the data so there might be assumptions I did which don't apply.

Comment: in first code: when `If r.value = r.Offset(1, 0).value Then` finds a match, `r.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete` will delete the row below _AND_ `Set r = r.Offset(1, 0)` will skip to the next one. While this latter shouldn't happen as there could be more than one consecutive cell below the _current_ one and matching it.

Comment: in second code: the `Do While l <= LastRow And x(i, 2) = x(l, 2)` loop condition errors out when `l` assumes `LastRow+1` value because the `And` operator brings along the evaluation of both condtions, i.e. also `And x(i, 2) = x(l, 2)` is evaluated and errors out when `l` value is `LastRow+1` after the last `l = l + 1`

Comment: @DisplayName - Case: Three rows all matching in the "B" column - `r` points to the first row. After the matching and the adding of values, the 2nd row is deleted and the 3rd row becomes the 2nd row. Finally `r` advances to the next row (which was originally the 3rd) and since there is a match it will do more adding and deleting. And so on, until there isn't a match anymore.

Comment: @DisplayName - You are right. I need an exit condition before I check for matching. let me think about it.

Comment: @DisplayName - Ok fixed `DW2()`. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @ja72 thank you so much for the input, I´m slowly getting there but it´s still not 100% right. 
The problem with the first one ist that it doesn´t consider more that two values in a row because it skips the deleted row .
The second one has the right amount of rows but the sum seems not to be working. Gonna try figure out how to solve that, but in the meantime thank you so much

Comment: @ja72 I found a workaround for the first one, I had to put 'Else' instead of 'End If' and the 'End If' after 'Set r = r.Offset(1, 0)' , so in case the row was deleted it still would check the same row with the new values.
altough it works better than mine it´s very near (timeconsuming), the second one has more potential I think so I´m gonna try work on that

Comment: @ja72 the second one actually works very good, it just skips the very last row

Comment: @ja72 the second fix was as simple as taking out the = in 'If i_next >= LastRow' thank you so much